# UINavigationBar custom image for iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, iphone-6-plus

I have a custom image made by designer for UINavigationBar. I got 640x128 & 640x88 size slices for iPhone. My questions :

1. If I hide the status bar, do I use the 640x88 size or I still need to use 640x128,
2. For iPhone 6/6+ and also iPad, I don't know how do I reuse these images as the size & aspect ratio of Navigation bar is different.

FYI, image is made using gradient of colours from top to bottom (in the Y-axis). Even if I use stretchable UIImage, how do I solve the problem of navigation bar of different heights on each device ? I need to target iOS 7 & above.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this problem I just create three different image for iPhone 4/5/5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus.
The image resolutions is 320x64, 375x64@2x, 414x64@3x (height is 64 since I need background image for navigation bar + status bar)

Then I apply correct image on application init:

```
NSString * navBarImageName;

if (IS_IPHONE_6P) {
    navBarImageName = @"navBarBackground_iPhone6Plus";
} else if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
    navBarImageName = @"navBarBackground_iPhone6";
} else {
    navBarImageName = @"navBarBackground";
}

UIImage * navBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:navBarImageName];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 
In header you can define macros for different devices like

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)667) < DBL_EPSILON)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)736) < DBL_EPSILON)
```

And then if and else condition for this..

```
UIImageView *imageview;   
if (IS_IPHONE_5){
    imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
    imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage" ];
       [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageview];}
else if(IS_IPHONE_6){
    imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 55)];
    imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_albums6"];
}else if (IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS){
    imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 55)];
    imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_albums6"];
} else
{
      // 3.5 inch
    imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
    imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_album"];
}
```

and then add navigation subview

```
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageview];
```

**Note** : This code write in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear method so the navigation bar is set with your custom size...
I hope this will help

Comment: You should also check if its an iPhone or iPad idiom, like:

`#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom image for NavigationBar background, the first thing you should be thinking is dimensions of custom image.

**1)** **320x44** => background.png
**2)** **640x88** => background@2x.png
**3)** **1334x183** => background@3x.png

Use following code to add background image and to avoid any tiling in Navigation Bar's background image.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```